# Here Maps Transit API: Isochrone Search: 403 Error

Tags: here-api

I am having trouble retrieving isochrones for public transport using the HERE Maps API.

Specifically, we are using the public transport API with isochrone search feature as described here:
https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/transit/topics/resource-isochrone-search.html

When we make a request, and use the key allocated to us, we get a 403 permissions error.

If we use the API Explorer/Playground (https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/public_transit/isochrone-search) with the default/demo keys (already in place), then we get a 200 OK response. If we insert our own keys, the request appears to time out/not provide a response.

Any ideas on what we may be doing wrong?

Edit: Using a HERE Maps trial (90 day) account to test functionality.

Answer (score 0):

For using Public Transport API, you need some special agreement with data supplier even for evaluation. Use the Contact us link to request additional permission.

https://developer.here.com/contact-us

https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/transit/topics/coverage-information.html

Comment: Hello. Thanks I've contacted HereMaps using the form, but no reply. Is there anyway other way to contact you to request permission?